# Как сделать так, чтобы при джойне значение поля с одинаковым именем из второй таблицы не перезаписывало значение из первой?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Делаю выборку из двух таблиц с объединением:

```
SELECT * FROM `material` LEFT JOIN `material_group`
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в результате выборки id столбец был от первой таблицы.
При такой выборке как в примере id поля есть у обоих таблиц и, соответственно, в результате объединения там единичка (1).

Я решаю этот вопрос так

```
SELECT `material`.* , 
    `material_group`.`namegroup`, 
    `material_group`.`tech` 
FROM `material`
```

То есть, выбираю всю первую таблицу и перечисляю все столбцы второй, кроме id столбца второй, и все работает.

Но есть ли правило, по которому можно выбрать обе таблицы кроме одного столбца, что-то типа:

```
SELECT `material`.* , `material_group`,* (исключяя `material_group`,`id`)
```

Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Так таблиц две (как в первом запросе) или одна (как во втором)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мне нужно что бы в результате выборки id столбец был от первой таблице. При такой выборке как в примере id поля есть у обоих таблиц и соотвественно в результате объединения там единичка (1).

Если нужно не шашечки, а ехать, то

```
SELECT m.id as material_id, m.*, mg.* FROM material m LEFT JOIN material_group mg
```

Впрочем, кто нам мешает изменить порядок перезатирания? Мне кажется что сработает такой вариант

```
SELECT mg.*, m.* FROM material m LEFT JOIN material_group mg
```

В общем, в итоге самый простой вариант будет

```
SELECT *, material.id FROM material ...
```

поскольку перезапись происходит уже в PHP, и происходит тупо потому что в массиве не может быть двух элементов с одним и тем же индексом, самое последнее значение id перезапишет значение в итоговом массиве, полученном через fetch

Comment: Супер. Только * впереди замены as (иначе работать не будет)

Comment: Ваш первый запрос в MySQL однозначно даст Syntax error. Второй - тоже. LEFT JOIN не бывает без ON или USING.

Comment: @Akina не надо злопыхать. Как в вопросе, так и в ответе приведена значимая часть запроса, если вам доступно такое понятие. На первую же ошибку мне уже указал автор, я ее испрвляю, хотя это делает запрос скучнее

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии, спасибо, поправил.

Comment: @Ипатьев Не поленитесь в MySQL создать пару таблиц и попробовать выполнить на них Ваш первый запрос. Ответ сервера будет однозначным: `ERROR 1064 (42000)`.

Comment: Ага, уже поправил... но в таком варианте поле id будет выведено не дважды, а ажно трижды...

Answer (score 0):

Все работает

```
SELECT *, `material`.`id` as material_id FROM `material`
```

Comment: здесь мы получим новое поле material_id  как у меня в первом варианте. А чтобы получить нужное значение в поле id, надо писать без алиаса, `SELECT *, material.id FROM material`

Answer (score -1):

В запросах типа

```
SELECT material.* , material_group.*
FROM material.* , material_group
WHERE material.id = material_group.id
```

или

```
SELECT material.* , material_group.*
FROM material.* 
JOIN material_group ON material.id = material_group.id
```

поле id будет выведено дважды - для каждой таблицы.

Но если использовать форму

```
SELECT material.* , material_group.*
FROM material.* 
JOIN material_group USING (id)
```

то поле будет выведено только один раз. Правда, если поля имеют разные имена - увы...

**UPD:** Если поле связывания id не только одноимённое, но и единственное одноимённое, можно использовать

```
SELECT material.* , material_group.*
FROM material.* NATURAL JOIN material_group
```

Comment: если бы джойн шел по id, то этого вопроса бы не было

Comment: @Ипатьев Внимательно перечитайте вопрос. Особенно вот эту фразу: *id поля есть у обоих таблиц и соотвественно в результате объединения там единичка (1)*.

Comment: Я умею не только читать, но и понимать прочитанное. еще раз: если джойн идет по ид, то вопрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: @Ипатьев Поделитесь пониманием, по каким полям идёт связывание, а?

Comment: Для вопроса это не имеет значения.  Вопрос вообще не про джойн, а про обработку полей с одинаковыми полями при фетче в пхп

Comment: @Ипатьев В вопросе нет ни звука ни про фетч, ни про обработку, про пхп - только тег. Вы поняли, что суть вопроса в том, что автор не знает, как отличить по имени поле одной таблицы от поля другой? честь и хвала... вот только Вы не исключили поле из списка вывода, а наоборот, добавили ещё одно - правда, дав ему новое, уникальное имя, чтобы не путаться, что, вероятно, и устроило автора. А поле связывания имеет значение не для вопроса (кстати, и с джойном по id вопрос имеет смысл), а для Вашего комментария, отсюда и просьба поделиться пониманием.